# Isolate and separate one network into two

Tags: networking

[image]

Basically I want to be able to do something like this, is this possible?

The two computers showing the same IP address is an example of how I want it isolated. I know this is done with public wifi at restaurants in a similar way if they want one external public IP and don't want the subnet that the business machines are running on to be accessible by others.

Comment: What are the models of your switch and router?   Much of your design option depends on the available features of your equipment.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use two routers in order to do what you want. There are several ways to accomplish that, check out the link with pictures:

http://www.wikihow.com/Connect-Two-Routers

Comment: This method do not provide ample network separation in most business settings.  This is because it is trivial for an adversary to hop from the public network to the private.  Equipment with guest WiFi SSIDs can help, but not against attackers on the wire.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you require both computers to have the same IP address, you need to use 2 routers as @Cown said.  You would not need an "isolator" in ths scenario, as each router would run NAT and that would do the isolating.

Most businesses that run 2 (or more) logical networks simply purchase a router with "guest" functionality which allows the setup of more then 1 SSID [ WIFI Name], and your access depends on which SSID you connect to.  In this scenario you would expect different IP address ranges, but also better WIFI performance.

Comment: Yeah i was assuming the same IP for both hosts. But your solution is much more correct in how it should be accomplished. :-)

Comment: Most business run a layer 3 switch or run Router-on-a-stick and enforce VLAN/subnet separation with ACLs (Access Control Lists).  Multiple routers are used by businesses too small to using anything other than consumer-grade equipment.

Comment: @tdurden Consumer grade equipment very often has guest vlan functionality - and if not, can often me upgraded to by changing to dd-wrt

Comment: I do not disagree with the guest VLAN functionality on some consumer grade equipment.  Most businesses except for very small entities do not use consumer grade equipment.  They use SMB or Enterprise grade equipment.